# Crossplatform appium code for iOS and Android platform

Tags: java, android, ios, appium

I have written Appium code for Android platform and recently my organisation came with similar iOS app too.

I am planning to use same code for both platform.

I am successfully able to run the same code on both platform but organising code is getting difficult with every piece of code.

Guide with an appropriate approach to achieve.

My code on Android is running pretty good and same runs on iOS too.
I have created two sets of capabilities like:

Capabilities File:

```
protected static void initCapabilities() {
getDirectory();
//Android
//deviceName = "33009a1eaa0b32a7";
//DEVICE_NAME = "emulator-5554";
//AUTOMATION_NAME = "uiautomator2";
//PLATFORM_NAME = "Android";
//BUILD = "app-internal-release - 628.apk";
//app = new File(appDirectory, BUILD);
//iOS
PLATFORM_NAME = "iOS";
PLATFORM_VERSION = "12.1";
DEVICE_NAME = "iPhone XR";
AUTOMATION_NAME = "XCUITest";
BUILD = "Jiffle.app";

app = new File(iOSAppDirectory, BUILD);
System.out.println("Build picked is: "+app);
}
```

Launch Code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import Utils.ValidationUtils;
import Utils.LogUtils;
import Global.Constants;
import Global.SetDataInExcel;

import TestbedDataLibrary.TestCases;

import Access.Login;
import EventList.EventListing;
import MeetingList.MLElementRepositoryConstant;
import BadgeScan.BadgeScan;
import BookMeeting.RequestMeeting;
import QuickDemo.QuickDemo;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;

public class Launch extends Constants {
    private static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> androidDriver;
    private static IOSDriver<MobileElement> iosDriver;

    @BeforeTest
    private void setup() {
        initCapabilities();
        initAppData();
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", PLATFORM_NAME);
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", PLATFORM_VERSION);
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", DEVICE_NAME);
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", AUTOMATION_NAME);
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to Appium Server...");
            if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals("Android")) {
                System.out.println("Launching Android Driver...");
                androidDriver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            }
            else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals("iOS")) {
                System.out.println("Launching iOS Driver...");
                iosDriver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mle) {
            System.out.println("Caught exception in connecting to Appium Server!!!");
            mle.printStackTrace();
        }
//        androidDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        iosDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void Login() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Login Execution...");
        initTestBedData();
        long startTimeLogin = System.currentTimeMillis();

        iosDriver.switchTo().alert().accept();

        //Login.initLogin(androidDriver);
        Login.initLogin(iosDriver);
        SetDataInExcel.setTime(Constants.LoginTestBed, Constants.testSuiteSheet, startTimeLogin, "Login", 7);
    }
```

Please let me know if you need any other details.

Issue: My main concern is that while passing driver `Login.initLogin(androidDriver);` , how should I decide which driver should I pass?
Also, please suggest me some improvement here.

Comment: I have posted the answer, please check and let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

You can make one generic method which will return the androidDriver if the platformType is android and iosDriver if the platformType is ios and then you can use this method wherever you want to use the driver.
For example:

```
private static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> getDriver() throws IOException {
    if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals("Android")) {
        // setup the android driver
    } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals("iOS")) {
        // setup the ios driver
    }
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. This is the approach I took initially but the issue is that which driver should I pass to my method in `Login.initLogin(androidDriver);`

Comment: You have only one `driver` now which is of the AppiumDriver type, so you just need to pass that `driver`

Comment: But there are Android specific test I need to Perform, say, `pressKey` which is not allowed with `AppiumDriver`.

Comment: Currently, I am working on creating one another approach where I have created one Driver interface to be shared across all the testcase which will be delegated with Mobile & Appium driver and has to be set based on platform. Something like this: `if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals("Android")) {
androidDriver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
TestSessionContext.INSTANCE.setDriver(new MobileTestDriver(androidDriver));
} and else part for iOS`

Comment: Key events are supported by appiumdriver as well. Please refer to the following links, it will surely help you: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/keys/press-keycode/ and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent and it you are using appiumdriver, it will help to maintain your code in a much easier way.

Comment: I hope that helped you :)

Answer (score -1):

You can define **AppiumDriver** instead of separate **AndroidDriver** and **IOSDriver**.

```
private static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> getDriver() throws IOException {
    if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals("Android")) {
       driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    } else if (PLATFORM_NAME.equals("iOS")) {
       driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
    return driver;
}
```

In login test, you can use driver like following

```
@Test(priority = 1)
    public void Login() throws Exception {
        //other codes
        Login.initLogin(driver);
        //other codes
    }
```

> Now you don't need to switch your android or ios driver. you can simply use **driver**

Comment: Please check my comment in @Sameer's answer

Comment: In Login.initLogin you can pass **driver**. example **Login.initLogin(driver)**

Comment: There are lots of platform specific actions that is not directly supported by `AppiumDriver`

Comment: When you need AndroidDriver you can typeCast it like **((AndroidDriver) driver).doSomeTask...**